# Informix data casting from BYTE to TEXT

Tags: sql, select, informix, data-conversion

How to convert BYTE data in HEX format in Informix database to TEXT format as below
"43444c4c3d" -> "CDLL="

I am hoping for something like this:
select CAST (expr AS INTEGER) from sampletable

Comment: BYTE data is present by DB-Access for UNLOAD and LOAD in the hex format (two hex digits per byte).  Inside the database, it is stored as binary data — one byte per byte.  What you seem to want is to treat the BYTE blob as a TEXT blob.  Have you tried `CAST(blobcolumn AS TEXT)`?  I assume you have and that it failed — but you should say so.

Comment: Its working. thanks buddy.

Comment: This query worked: select cast(field_name as text)  from sample_table. I was trying to cast it as varchar and stuff like that and it didn't work earlier. Thanks again, this saves me some time in coding on the service front.